# iptables to nftables for iKEv2 IPSEC VPN server

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, ipsec, nftables

Can someone please help in converting the below **iptable rules** to equivalent **nftables rules**?

*I have already tried to use iptables-translate, but it is not translating all of my rules...*

```
# accept ports 500 and 4500, required for IKEv2
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT

# forward ESP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in  --proto esp -s 10.1.1.1/24 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.1.1.1/24 -j ACCEPT

# more forwarding
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.1/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.1/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

# fix fragmentation
sudo iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.1.1.1/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
```

---

**Any help would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am looking for assistance to convert the listed iptable commands to equivalent nftable rules...

So instead of executing

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT

What would be the equivalent command for nftables?

Something like
sudo nft add xxxxxxxxx

Comment: Looks like homework: I didn't try [to understand] anything, let's ask SU to do it for me.